# redux-persist not updating local storage even after successful dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

In my app on log out I'm doing `this.props.dispatch(setUserSession({}))` even passed null here. After dispatching in redux-logger I can see that it's changed to

```
action {type: "SET_USER_SESSION", userSession: {}}

next state {userSession: {}
```

But in local storage, I can still see the userSession that was there before dispatching null.
On what action or when will the persisted store will get updated.

I'm setting userSession to null on logout, but when the user refreshes the page, he is back in without login since the token is present in the store.

And also I don't want to do a purge or flush the full store, just that userSession key.

Current store configuration

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

import reducer from './reducers';

let middleware = [thunk];

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const configureStore = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware))(createStore);

const config = {
 key: 'root',
 storage
};

const combinedReducer = persistReducer(config, reducer);
const store = configureStore(combinedReducer);
const persistor = persistStore(store);

export { persistor, store };
```

Kindly provide some help, correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Can you post the configuration of redux-persist inside your application?

Comment: Updated question with the store configuration.

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: The local store has a limit of around 5MB. In my case the storage was full. After reducing the payload it started working. Make sure you're not filling up the store.